# How to do mathematical comparision with SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql

I have a student table around 100k records and I have two types of data in it: student name and level type with selection values primary, secondary, intermediate & university

I want to filter out the student from this table, whose have count > 0, in all level primary, secondary, intermediate & university

I was able to find the sum for each student in each level using the following query

```
SELECT 
    student_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN lev_type = 'primary' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS primary,
    SUM(CASE WHEN lev_type = 'secondary' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS secondary,
    SUM(CASE WHEN lev_type = 'intermediate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS intermediate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN level_type = 'university' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS university 
FROM
    student_details
GROUP BY
    student_id
```

and I am getting a result like (note that my result is 92242 row(s))

```
attendee_id     primary secondary   intermediate    uni
    student1    0        1                1          2
    student2    0        1                1          0
    student3    88       209              92         32
    student4    0        1                1          0
    student5    0        1                1          0
```

How to filter out student3 from this result?

Comment: I would change lakh to the English equivlant

Comment: @gh9: or better yet - the **internationally understood** unit of measurement - like thousands, millions, billions etc.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` might get you what you want.  For example:

```
SELECT student_id,
   sum(case when lev_type  = 'primary' then 1 else 0 end) as primary,
   sum(case when  lev_type  = 'secondary' then 1 else 0 end)  as secondary ,
   sum(case when  lev_type  = 'intermediate' then 1 else 0 end)  as intermediate ,
  sum(case when  level_type  = 'university' then 1 else 0 end) as university 
from student_details
group by student_id
-- Put the criteria here by which you want to filter
having sum(case when lev_type  = 'primary' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
    and sum(case when  lev_type  = 'secondary' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
    and sum(case when  lev_type  = 'intermediate' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
    and sum(case when  level_type  = 'university' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a where statement as follows:

```
SELECT student_id,
      SUM(case when lev_type  = 'primary' then 1 else 0 end) as primary,
      SUM(case when lev_type  = 'secondary' then 1 else 0 end)  as secondary ,
      SUM(case when lev_type  = 'intermediate' then 1 else 0 end)  as intermediate ,
      SUM(case when lev_type  = 'university' then 1 else 0 end) as university 
 FROM student_details
 GROUP BY student_id
 WHERE primary = 0 OR secondary = 0 OR intermediate = 0 OR university  = 0
```